# Getting error while running sonarqube scanner

Tags: .net, sonarqube, sonar-runner

Getting the following error in SonarQube while running the build from TeamCity

Caused by: Start pointer [line=239, lineOffset=1] should be before end pointer [line=239, lineOffset=1]

Updated the C# plugin, installed VB.net plugin and added the Scanner for MSBUILD latest version sonar-scanner-msbuild-2.2.0.24.

Still getting the error.

Comment: Even we were facing this issue. We were using sonar-csharp-plugin-5.5.0.479.jar. Then, we tried with sonar-csharp-plugin-5.3.2.jar and it worked. I guess it has something to do with the size of the project. Our project was having LOC 528,799. Thanks to my colleague Praveen Rekhapalli who found this workaround. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately we introduced a bug in the latest release. Here's the corresponding ticket: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARCS-629. We're working on the fix.

As a workaround for the time being you can disable the rule that causes the issue. Can you confirm that in your case it is S105 (tab characters should not be used)?

Comment: we have disabled the rule and now the analysis is completed without any errors. Please let us know when the bug will be fixed.

Comment: I updated again to 6.1 of SonarQube with C# Plugin version 5.5.0.479. Unfortunately, I get the same error: `ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Start pointer [line=90, lineOffset=89] should be before end pointer [line=90, lineOffset=89] `. I also tried disabling rule S105. But that did not solve it for me.

Comment: @tobre Can you check the encoding of your files? I suspect that you have non UTF-8 files, which causes similar problems. See https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARCS-634.

Comment: @Tamas: I had to change the file encoding for 110 source files to UTF-8. Now the problem is solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled in this issue while instrumenting a large .NET project: I'm using sonarqube 6.1 with SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 2.2.0.24.

At first, I downloaded and installed the csharp plugin C# 5.5.0.479 copying the corresponding jar file into the sonarqube dedicated dir: THIS IS WRONG!

Reading into the MSBuild scanner documentation I learned that msbuild scanner provides itself the correct csharp handler, so, I stopped sonar, I went into  sonarqube-6.1\extensions\plugins and I deleted the csharp related jar file.
I restarted sonar and then I repeated the begin - build - end sequence and everything worked for me.

I hope this could be of help.

Comment: We need to disable the S104 rule also to get rid of this error.

Comment: 'til now I've found this error triggered by three different issues:

Comment: Sorry for the partial comment above, anyway, the three issues are: 1. Utf-8-BOM enabled files, 2. S104 enabled and 3.Using the MSBuild scanner with a CSharp plugin downloaded separately from the scanner.