# SonarQube Scanner IllegalArgumentException

Tags: .net, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

After running SonarQube Scanner 2.2.0.24 I got the error message below but it does not help at all. I am running with with the `d:sonar.log.level=TRACE` flag.

Any tip on this one?

> \SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end 
>   1>d:\tb\logs\sonar.end.log.20161711.txt 19:20:53.674 ERROR: Error
>   during SonarQube Scanner execution java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Start pointer [line=3, lineOffset=0] should be before end pointer
>   [line=3, lineOffset=0]
>           at org.sonar.api.internal.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument
>   (Preconditions.java:145)
>           at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.DefaultInputFile.newRangeValidPointer
>   s(DefaultInputFile.java:254)
>           at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.DefaultInputFile.newRange(DefaultInpu
>   tFile.java:238)
>           at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.AbstractSensor$SarifParserCallb
>   ackImplementation.onIssue(AbstractSensor.java:144)
>           at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.sarif.SarifParser01And04.handleAnalysis
>   TargetElement(SarifParser01And04.java:109)
>           at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.sarif.SarifParser01And04.handleIssue(Sa
>   rifParser01And04.java:73)
>           at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.sarif.SarifParser01And04.handleIssues(S
>   arifParser01And04.java:55)
>           at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.sarif.SarifParser01And04.parse(SarifPar
>   ser01And04.java:43)
>           at org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpSensor.importRoslynReport(CSharpSensor
>   .java:183)
>           at org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpSensor.executeInternal(CSharpSensor.ja
>   va:118)
>           at org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpSensor.execute(CSharpSensor.java:85)
>           at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:53)
>
> ```
>     at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecuto
> ```
>
> r.java:57)
>           at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java
>   :49)
>           at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseE
>   xecutor.java:78)
>           at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanCon
>   tainer.java:184)
>           at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentC
>   ontainer.java:142)
>           at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer
>   .java:127)
>           at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer
>   .java:241)
>           at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectSc
>   anContainer.java:236)
>           at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectSc
>   anContainer.java:234)
>           at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanC
>   ontainer.java:226)
>           at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentC
>   ontainer.java:142)
>           at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer
>   .java:127)
>           at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
>           at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:
>   86)
>           at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentC
>   ontainer.java:142)
>           at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer
>   .java:127)
>           at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContain
>   er.java:115)
>           at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:118)
>           at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.exec
>   ute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(Iso
>   latedLauncherProxy.java:60)
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
>           at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner
>   .java:233)
>           at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScann
>   er.java:151)
>           at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:110)
>           at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:74)
>           at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61) 19:20:53.674 ERROR: 19:20:53.674 ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using
>   the -X switch to enable full debug logging. The SonarQube Scanner did
>   not complete successfully 19:20:53.845  Post-processing failed. Exit
>   code: 1

Comment: Stack trace is the same as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40591731/error-during-sonarqube-scanner-execution-illegal-argument-exception

Comment: My sonar.scm.disabled flag is true and the other post it is set to false so I dont get any scm issue like in the other.

Comment: scm warning is completely unrelated to stack trace

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/dsq9jkTCP5I