# SonarQube does not analyses code after upgrading it from 5.6.6 to 6.7.2

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I recently have upgraded sonarqube installation to 6.7.2 from 5.6.6.
On 5.6.6 analysis for all modules was working fine however, once SonarQube was upgraded to 6.7.2 it is giving below exception for one of the module. for other modules it works fine.

Exception:

```
[17:08:04]ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
[17:08:04]ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
[17:08:04]ERROR: Caused by: Start pointer [line=19, lineOffset=23] should be before end pointer [line=19, lineOffset=23]
[17:08:04]ERROR: 
[17:08:04]ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarQube Runner with the -e switch.
[17:08:04]ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[17:08:04]Process exited with code 1
```

I tried to change file encoding to plane UTF-8, Tried disabling rule S104 nothing worked.

However when I installed SonarQube 6.7.2 on new blank database everything works fine. in this case I looses analysis history which I don't want.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you omit the stacktrace? If so, please [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: I am executing sonarqube from TeamCity. No stacktrace is available in build logs. it analyses all files and the end when it starts importing analysis results from .sonar\output-cs files it gives above exception. more details are

Comment: So then what lead you to disable rule S104 (and in which language?)?

Comment: I initially tried to find solution on net where I came across below link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40379930/getting-error-while-running-sonarqube-scanner. here one of the possible cause of exception was S104. I am analysing code for C#

Comment: Lucky you! If only I could get rid of SonarQube as easily.